# INVALID_VALUE: uniform2fv: invalid srcOffset + srcLength

Tags: glsl, matrix-engine

I wann pass simple array uniform to the shader.

Any suggestion ?

in GL program :

```js
var myshaderDrawData = [
   0.5, 0.7,
   0.62, 0.3,
   0.5, 0.7,
   0.38, 0.3,
   0.43, 0.46,
   0.57, 0.46];

...

  world.GL.gl.uniform1f(object.shaderProgram.myshaderDrawData, myshaderDrawData)
```

Shader:

```c
#version 300 es
precision highp float;
// Standard matrix-engine params
in vec2 vTextureCoord;
in vec3 vLightWeighting;
uniform sampler2D uSampler;

uniform float[12] myshaderDrawData;

uniform vec2 iResolution;
uniform float iTime;
uniform float iTimeDelta;
uniform vec3 iMouse;

uniform float iXXX;
uniform float iR;
uniform float iG;
uniform float iB;

out vec4 outColor;

#define Thickness 0.003

float line(vec2 uv, vec2 pt1, vec2 pt2, vec2 iResolution) {
  float clrFactor = 0.1f;
  float tickness = iXXX * 0.1f / max(iResolution.x, iResolution.y);
  float r = distance(uv, pt1) / distance(pt1, pt2);

  float r2 = distance(uv, pt2) / distance(pt2, pt1);

  if(r <= .90f && r2 <= 0.90f) {
    vec2 ptc = mix(pt1, pt2, r);
    float dist = distance(ptc, uv);
    if(dist < tickness / 2.0f) {
      clrFactor = 2.0f;
    }
  }
  return clrFactor;
}

// for matrix-engine - loading strip line data.
void createStripLines(out vec4 outColor, vec2[6] mePoints) {
  vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
  vec3 color = vec3(.5f, 0.7f, 1.0f);
  for(int i = 0; i < mePoints.length();i = i + 2) {
    // int i = 0;
    float lf = line(uv, mePoints[i], mePoints[i+1], iResolution.xy);
    outColor += vec4(color * lf, 1.f);
  }
}

// for matrix-engine - loading strip line data.
void createStripLinesF(out vec4 outColor, float[12] mePoints) {
  vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
  vec3 color = vec3(.5f, 0.7f, 1.0f);
  for(int i = 0; i < mePoints.length();i = i + 4) {
    // int i = 0;
    float lf = line(uv, vec2(mePoints[i], mePoints[i+1]), vec2(mePoints[i+2], mePoints[i+4]), iResolution.xy);
    outColor += vec4(color * lf, 1.f);
  }
}


void main() {
  // vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy; // current point
  vec2 pt1 = vec2(0.5f, 0.7f);
  vec2 pt2 = vec2(0.62f, 0.3f);
  vec2 pt11 = vec2(0.5f, 0.7f);
  vec2 pt21 = vec2(0.38f, 0.3f);
  vec2 pt12 = vec2(0.43f, 0.46f);
  vec2 pt22 = vec2(0.57f, 0.46f);
  //  1.2 1.3 support
  // const float mePoints[4] = float[4](0.5f, 0.7f, 0.62f, 0.3f);

  vec2 mePoints[] = vec2[6](pt1, pt2, pt11, pt21, pt12, pt22);

  // working - draw from shader inline data
  // createStripLines(outColor, mePoints);
 
  createStripLinesF(outColor, myshaderDrawData);
  

  vec4 textureColor = texture(uSampler, vTextureCoord) * vec4(1, 1, 1, 1);
  outColor.rgb *= vec3(textureColor.rgb * vLightWeighting);
}
```